# What is the nature of $e^{ix}$, real or complex?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, real-numbers, eulers-number-e

Since, $e^{i\pi}=-1$,

right part of the equation ($-1$) is real and left part is seemingly complex as

$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ which is a complex number( I am not sure though).

I am a freshman, and don't know much regarding Euler's equations and advanced Mathematics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Real numbers are also complex numbers; their imaginary part is $0$.  If $x$ is a real number then $e^{ix}$ is, in general, complex, but, in special cases, it can be real.  The only real numbers of the form $e^{ix}$ ($x$ real) are $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score -1):

Because $e^{ix}=\cos(x) + i\sin(x)$, it is only "real" when $\sin(x) = 0$, namely when $x = n \pi$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. For every other value of $x$, $e^{ix}$ has a complex component. Note that I put "real" with quotes because $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What about $x=4\pi$? $0$ and $\pi$ are not the only values of $x$.

Comment: Please add the range restriction **or** the $+2\pi k$ where $k \in \mathbb Z$